# Firebird throwing exceptions at simple queries

Tags: php, firebird

I'm making kind of an external plugin for my friend which, for the first time in my life, involves dealing with Interbase/Firebird engine.

I've got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE T_KLIENT (
ID_KLIENTA INTEGER NOT NULL,
NAZWA PL_VARCHAR250 NOT NULL,
WOJEWODZTWO PL_VARCHAR50 NOT NULL,
MIASTO PL_VARCHAR50 NOT NULL,
POCZTA POCZTA NOT NULL,
ADRES PL_VARCHAR50,
OS_KONTAKT PL_VARCHAR100,
TELEFON PL_VARCHAR30,
FAX PL_VARCHAR30,
NIP PL_VARCHAR30,
EMAIL PL_VARCHAR100,
ID_SCENARIUSZA LICZBA,
RAPORTOWANIE LICZBA,
UWAGI PL_VARCHAR250,
KRS PL_VARCHAR30,
FAKTUROWANIE LICZBA,
KONTO PL_VARCHAR50,
AC KOD_OZNACZENIA_NULL,
STATUS LICZBA,
KOD_KLIENTA PL_VARCHAR30 NOT NULL,
NR_KLIENTA PL_VARCHAR30 NOT NULL,
ID_KATEGORII LICZBA DEFAULT -1,
ID_ODDZIALU INTEGER default 0,
RYCZALT_KWOTA KWOTA,
GODZ_RYCZALT LICZBA DEFAULT 0,
KWOTA_GODZ_POZARYCZALT KWOTA,
ONLINE_LOGIN PL_VARCHAR10,
ONLINE_PASSWORD PL_VARCHAR30,
PRZEDSTAWICIEL_KOD KOD_OZNACZENIA_NULL,
F_PROWIZJA_KAPITAL "DProcenty" DEFAULT 0,
F_PROWIZJA_ODSETKI "DProcenty" DEFAULT 0,
ORGANREJESTROWY PL_VARCHAR250,
REGON PL_VARCHAR100,
STRONA_WWW PL_VARCHAR100,
TELEFON_GSM PL_VARCHAR30,
BRANZA PL_VARCHAR100,
RODZAJ_PODMIOTU PL_VARCHAR100,
NR_DOMU PL_VARCHAR10);
```

this function

```
 function FDB_addClient($client_name, $client_address, $client_postal, $client_city, $client_country, $client_vat) {
    $get_total_client_count = ($this->FDB_getTotalClientCount()+1);
    $set_query = ibase_query($this->fb_db, "INSERT INTO T_KLIENT VALUES (".$get_total_client_count.", '".$client_name."', '---', '".$client_city."', '".$client_postal."', '".$client_address."', 'Brak', 'Brak', 'Brak', '".$client_vat."', 'Brak', NULL, NULL, 'Brak', NULL, NULL, 'Brak', NULL, NULL, '".$client_vat."', '".$client_vat."', -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Brak', 'Brak', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)") or die(ibase_errcode().'-'.ibase_errmsg());
    if ($set_query) { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

and this very error I can't get rid of

```
Warning: ibase_query(): exception @1 @1 @1 @1 in C:\WebServ\httpd\core.php on line 37
-836-exception @1 @1 @1 @1
```

Unfortunately, the Internet is so poor in any decent support for Firebird and it's overwhelmingly frustrating.

I'd appreciate any hint. Thank you in advance!

@Edit

Specifying columns does not help.

```
function FDB_addClient($client_name, $client_address, $client_postal, $client_city, $client_country, $client_vat) {
    $get_total_client_count = ($this->FDB_getTotalClientCount()+1);
    $set_query = ibase_query($this->fb_db, "INSERT INTO T_KLIENT (ID_KLIENTA, NAZWA, WOJEWODZTWO, MIASTO, POCZTA, ADRES, OS_KONTAKT, TELEFON, FAX, NIP, EMAIL, ID_SCENARIUSZA, RAPORTOWANIE, UWAGI, KRS, FAKTUROWANIE, KONTO, AC, STATUS, KOD_KLIENTA, NR_KLIENTA, ID_KATEGORII, ID_ODDZIALU, RYCZALT_KWOTA, GODZ_RYCZALT, KWOTA_GODZ_POZARYCZALT, ONLINE_LOGIN, ONLINE_PASSWORD, PRZEDSTAWICIEL_KOD, F_PROWIZJA_KAPITAL, F_PROWIZJA_ODSETKI, ORGANREJESTROWY, REGON, STRONA_WWW, TELEFON_GSM, BRANZA, RODZAJ_PODMIOTU, NR_DOMU) VALUES (".$get_total_client_count.", '".$client_name."', '---', '".$client_city."', '".$client_postal."', '".$client_address."', 'Brak', 'Brak', 'Brak', '".$client_vat."', 'Brak', NULL, NULL, 'Brak', NULL, NULL, 'Brak', NULL, NULL, '".$client_vat."', '".$client_vat."', -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Brak', 'Brak', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)") or die(ibase_errcode().'-'.ibase_errmsg());
    if ($set_query) { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

Comment: try explicitly specifiying all the columns in the `INSERT INTO` query. it might be defaulting the column names in a different order than you expect

Comment: Does not work. Nothing changes.

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the firebird client library installation (eg wrong version, or the InterBase library instead of Firebird), as normally you'd get a human readable error message. You might want to try to execute the query in a different tool (eg isql, or flamerobin) to get the actual error message (although if you have the wrong client install that might lead to the same problem).  And as Sarfaraaz says: explicitly specify your columns!

Comment: I've got fbclient.dll installed, and it says its version is 2.0.5.13206. Specifying columns did not help. Nothing changed.

Comment: IIRC the PHP ibase support uses gds32.dll instead of fbclient.dll. So you either need to install gds32.dll (using `<firebird>\bin\instclient.exe i g`, or using the installer (enable option generate (or install) legacy gds32.dll). It might also mean that fbclient.dll can't find firebird.msg (which contains the error messages).

Comment: I put your php query parts and table columns next to each. not sure if I got it right here is a [pic](http://ibin.co/25lDYm9KKqun)

Comment: @Sarfaraaz Good call, I tried counting but after two tries I gave up ;)

Comment: @Sarfaraaz: the count is good; it's 38. There's no doubled 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL.

Comment: Okay, I updated  my fbclient.dll and this is more comprehensible error: -836-exception 28 NR_KL_UZYTY Podany numer jest ju� u�yty. Wybierz inny numer. At trigger 'T_KLIENT_BI' line: 7, col: 102 - that translates into "28 NR_KL_USED Given number is already in use. Please choose another number."

Comment: In that case the problem is in the trigger that is defined on the table (or with the ID number that you set in the query). It looks like you have a before insert trigger that does some validation, and this is the error message it returns for a validation failure.

Comment: Does your Id's start at 0? because `getTotalClientCount()+1` would give you 2 then then during the following runs it may produce an id that has been assigned. maybe use a query `SELECT TOP 1 ID_KLIENTA FROM T_KLIENT ORDER BY ID_KLIENTA DESC` then add 1

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Sarfaraaz, but now I am dealing with more irritating error - ibase_query(): conversion error from string "", and it is driving me nuts, because the code is right, the values are right, column count is right and well. An error. I think I'm gonna hate Firebird.

Comment: @user3027309 That means you are trying to insert an empty string into a column that is not a string type, and empty string is not convertible into that type.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by updating fbclient.dll for more comprehensible errors and reading triggers embedded into the database.

Thanks to all users involved.